# Interaction between ReadConcern and ReadPreference in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

##### Question 1. Is my understanding of the concepts correct?

**ReadConcerns:**

- `local` - returns data from any single instance, and thus may return outdated state, or state that will be rolled back.
- `majority` - returns data from single instance **that has been majority acknowledged**, and thus may return outdated state, but never state that will be rolled back.
- `linearizable` - returns data from primary **that has been majority acknowledged and waits for any concurrent operations on the same document to complete**, and thus will never return outdated state or state that will be rolled back. When applied to an operation that may return multiple documents, only provides same guarantees as `majority`.
- `snapshot` - provides same guarantees as `majority`, but eliminates anomalies that may arise from sharding (?). Not sure I really understand this one.

**ReadPreferences:**

- `primary` - reads from primary, and thus will never return outdated state, but may return state that will be rolled back if primary is reelected before the write propagates to secondaries.
- any non-`primary` option - may read data from a secondary, and thus may return outdated state or state that may be rolled back, unless `ReadConcern` of choice implies stronger guarantees.

##### Question 2. How do the concepts interact?

So for instance if I use `linearizable` read concern and a non-`primary` read preference, will my request be rerouted to primary, ignoring the preference, to uphold guarantees of linearizability? If my read concern is `local` but read preference is `primary`, does it mean that I will never get outdated state, but may get state that will be rolled back? Is read concern `majority` combined with read preference `primary` essentially the same as read concern `linearizable`?

##### Question 3. What does it mean in practice for an app developer?

As an app developer, is it enough to use a non-`primary` read preference in all operations, and use appropriate read concerns depending on the situation? Are there any situations when I should use `primary` read preference? What are some examples of combinations that make sense in certain cases?